# How to create a read-only user in Azure PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, postgresql-9.1, azure-postgresql

I'm trying to create a new user in postgresql which have read only access to Databases. I followed this [document](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-create-read-only-user-in-postgresql/) I will just list out the commands I used 
`CREATE ROLE readaccess;` 
`GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db_name TO readaccess;` 
`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readaccess;` 
`GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readaccess;` 
For this I got the **output** as `ERROR:  permission denied for table log`

I executed this commands as root user. I do check other blogs, all of them mentioned steps similar to this.

I tried `SELECT * from log;` 
I was getting the output as `ERROR:  permission denied for table log`

The root user have attributes : **Create role, Create DB** and 
 member of : **{pg_read_all_settings,pg_read_all_stats,pg_stat_scan_tables,azure_pg_admin}**

Can anyone help me on this, or share any of your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Please try below and see if it helps:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user_name;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for adding the comment. I tried this command and it executed without any error. But on executing `SELECT * FROM <tablename>` I'm getting error as `ERROR:  permission denied for table <tablename>` If the user is having readpermission theis command should work right ? Or I'm I missing something ?

Comment: Try this: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;

Comment: Thanks, I will try and give an update.what I'm not getting is, even the root user is not able to execute pg_dumb this is the error               pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table log

pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE public.log IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

Comment: 1) [ sudo ] su postgres 2) psql 3) GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <user>; 4) GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <user>;

Comment: I have tried this too, but getting same error as I mentioned above. If my application is not running, there is no such error, otherwise there will issues.

Comment: Please try afresh and see if this happens for other users too.

Comment: I tried with a user having full PRIVILEGES, still having same issue